# html5 picture tag does not work on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been programming quite a long grid system, where I used the html5 `<picture>` tag. When a device is `< 650px` there should load [picture 1](http://vouzalis.dk/380.jpg), and `> 650` [picture 2](http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg). I was testing this with minimize chrome browser.

The fallback picture is a [test picture](http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg).

I now test this on an iPhone, and I can see the fallback picture is loaded everytime. So now I panic because I used 3 days for making this grid, and it looks like the main purpose of making the grid is not working.

[See the demosite here](http://vouzalis.dk/test.html).

Does anybody have a clue of why it is not working?
(I cut away a lot of code, there is not relevant for the question. But I posted all the CSS that I am using)
.

```css
#front .row {
    padding-bottom: 0px!important;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  /* Set width between grid elements */
  
  .small-padding.top {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  
  .small-padding.bottom {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .small-padding.left {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .small-padding.right {
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  
  .margin_bottom {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .row {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
  }
  
  .img-responsive {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  /* Position of buttons/text in a single grid element */
  
  .inner-wrapper {
    background: none;
  }
  
  .centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  
  .bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 6%;
  }
/* Position text on full width banner */
  .header-container {
    color: white;
    margin: 0 5%;
  }
  .banner-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16%;
    left: 6%;
  }
  
  /* Color on text */
  
  .dark-font {
    color: #333;
  }
  
  .light-font {
    color: #fff;
  }
   
  /* Set full width on columns */
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .img-responsive {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    /* Maybe delete btn-success: */
    .btn-success {
      width: fit-content;
    }
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    h3 {
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }
  }
  .image-overlay {
    position:relative;
  }
  .overlay {
    position:absolute;
    transition:all .3s ease;
    opacity:0;
    transition:1.9s;
    background: #00b1bab8;
  }
  .image-overlay:hover .overlay {
    opacity:1;
  }
  .overlayFade {
    background: rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.5);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>FINAL WORKING</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
              <div class="image-overlay">
                  <a href="#">
                      <picture>
                          <div class="overlay overlayFade"></div>
                          <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg"></source>
                          <source media="(min-width: 380px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/380.jpg"></source>
                          <img src="http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_830/s_f/o_1/cx_98/cy_0/cw_640/ch_360/APL/uploads/2015/07/cecil-AP463227356214-1000x400.jpg" alt="John Doe" style="width:100%;"></img>
                      </picture>
                      <div class="inner-wrapper banner-text">
                          <div class="header-container">
                              <h2 class="light-font">Here is headline 1</h2>
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                              <span class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Our Services</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried different selectors in source media queries - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Ah ha okay. I looked at your link, and changed the `<source media="(min-width: 380px)` to `<source media="(min-width: 320px)`, and it works now. Thank you for this. Should your suggestion be closed with an answer? Hopefully it works on devices that I cannot test on :-/